# Partition interval in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-cd

I want to draw this partitioned interval. I've used Tikz but I don't know how to add the underbrace for the nodes. Thanks.[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. In this case, the `Tikz` code for your diagram (without the brace) would be very helpful for other users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want, but to draw a brace between two nodes you can use the tikz library `decorations.pathreplacing`:

[image]

The basic syntax is:

`\draw[decorate,decoration=brace](x1)--(x2);`

To draw the brace *below* the nodes, use `decoration={brace,mirror}`. In the code below I added `raise=5mm` to get the brace below the labels of the nodes. You can then create another node to label the brace as in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{tick/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum width=0pt, minimum height=2mm, inner sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2]
\draw(0,0)node[tick,label=below:$x_1$](x1){}
    --(1,0)node[tick,label=below:$x_2$](x2){}
    --(2,0)node[label=below:$\dots$]{}
    --(3,0)node[tick,label=below:$x_n$](xn){}
    --(4,0)node[tick,label=below:$x_{n+1}$](xn1){};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5mm}](x1)--node[below,yshift=-6mm]{$y$}(x2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!